# Materials to read for Graph Theory.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, random-graphs, planar-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

I am interested in graph theory and currently finished learning the basic knowledge in graph theory. Before I continue on to study the following three branch of graph theory, namely Topological Graph Theory, Algebraic Graph Theory and Probabilistic Graph Theory, what particular books in topology, algebra and probability is required for me as an entry to all those branches of graph theory ?

Comment: For Algebraic Graph Theory  check out "A Course in Group Theory" by John F. Humphreys (ISBN-10: 0198534590) and "Examples of Groups" by Michael Weinstein (ISBN-10: 0936428015)